# How can I convert database query results to an array?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, mono

How would I convert the results returned in a MySQL query to an array in C# .Net/Mono

To my understanding you need to define arrays with the number of items the array will hold but I understand that the DataReader doesn't tell you have many row was returned. so how can I define a array.

So far I have:

```
string sqlWhere;

        if ((name != None) && (name != ""))
            sqlWhere = "WHERE name LIKE '%"+name+"%'";

        if ((company != None) && (company != ""))
            if (sqlWhere == "")
                sqlWhere = "WHERE company LIKE '%"+company+"%'";
            else
                sqlWhere = sqlWhere + " AND company LIKE '%"+company+"%'";

        if ((dateFrom != None) && (dateFrom != "") && (dateTo != None) && (dateTo != ""))
            if (sqlWhere == "")
                sqlWhere = "WHERE date(timestampIn) BETWEEN '"+dateFrom+"' AND '"+dateTo+"'";
            else
                sqlWhere = sqlWhere + " AND date(timestampIn) BETWEEN '"+dateFrom+"' AND '"+dateTo+"'";

        IDbCommand dbcmd = this.dbcon.CreateCommand();
        dbcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM visitors " + sqlWhere;

                    MySqlDataReader Reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (Reader.Read())
            {

            }
```

Comment: with the above code you are wide open to SQL injection - which is a serious security problem!

Comment: Why do you want an array? It's almost always a bad idea to create one.  You can bind a datareader directly to a grid, if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

```
public IList<Group> GetGroup()
        {
            Connection c = new Connection();
            String connectionString = c.ConnectionName;
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand mycmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            DataSet dspendingapps = new DataSet();
            dspendingapps.Clear();

            mycmd.CommandText = " select g.groupid,g.groupname from tbl_group g order by g.groupname ";
            conn.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter appreader = new OleDbDataAdapter(mycmd);
            appreader.Fill(dspendingapps);
            conn.Close();

            IList<Group> g = new List<Group>();

            foreach (DataRow drapp in dspendingapps.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                Group gg = new Group();
                gg.GroupId = Convert.ToInt16(drapp["groupid"]);
                gg.Name = drapp["groupname"].ToString();
                g.Add(gg);

            }
            return g;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `DataReader`, use a `DataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`. You can see the total number of rows in the resulting `DataTable`.

```
var results = new DataTable();

var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = dbcmd;
dapater.Fill(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List<T>` enter code here instead of array to store your data where T is the type of data you want to store e.g. string, int or your custom data type. For using Arrays, we need to specify the length at compile time but with `List<T>` we can store data without worrying about the length.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Deepansh Gupta's response:  You might consider creating a custom object or structure whose internal data fields correspond to the columns returned in your query result set (i.e., each object corresponds to a data row, each data variable in the object corresponds to columnar data).  As your code goes through each row of the results, create a new custom object and append it to your List.